# iOS Bluetooth is not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, bluetooth

My intention is to check whether my device's (iPhone 6) Bluetooth is working or not. For this, I tried following code. But when I tried with fail bluetooth device, it is not calling delegate. I got the reason, as bluetooth is not working thats why delegates not getting call. But how I determine, bluetooth is not working for iPhone or Bluetooth has some issue.

```
-(void)callBluetooth
{
    start = [NSDate date];

    NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO], CBCentralManagerOptionShowPowerAlertKey, nil];

    ce = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:options];
}

#pragma mark - Bluetooth Delegate

- (void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{

    if (central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOff) {
        status = CASE_STATUS_SKIPPED;
    }
    else if(!(central.state == CBCentralManagerStateUnsupported) && central.state == CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn){
        if ([central respondsToSelector:@selector(scanForPeripheralsWithServices:options:)]) {
            status = CASE_STATUS_PASS;
        }
        else{
            status = CASE_STATUS_FAIL;
        }

    }
    else{
        status = CASE_STATUS_FAIL;
    }
    [self performSelector:@selector(callDelegate) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];

}
```

Comment: Your first step in checking if there is a problem with your iDevice is Apple Support: https://getsupport.apple.com . I believe you can run a hardware check through the site although I have never done so myself.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but my intention is to create an application that will diagnosis bluetooth means bluetooth of the device is working or not.